# extending generic type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I was trying to understand TS code snippet

```
interface CommonFields {
  createdAt: number
  updatedAt: number
}

interface DriverCommonApi<T extends CommonFields, S extend string> {
 eventType: S
 object: "event"
 data: {
  object: CommonFields
 }
}
```

Here what does `T extends CommonFields, S extend string` mean? Also how can I create a new type that uses DriverCommonApi

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [TypeScript generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [generic with a constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints), saying that the `DriverCommonApi` interface has 2 type parameters, the first one extends `CommonFields`, and the second extends `string`. To extend it, feed it the type parameters:

```
class Foo implements DriverCommonApi<CommonFields, string> {
    // ...
}
```

Or any subtypes of `CommonFields` or `string` (`"foo"` would be a subtype of `string`, and any implementor of `CommonFields` would be a subtype of `CommonFields`).